# FancyBox No Longer Darkens Background, Worked Fine Until Recent Update

Tags: javascript, css

So as title says it, fancybox is no longer darkening out the background.  It functions and works normally, but won't darken.

Example from my site: http://www.remodeling-buffalo.com/gallery.php

One strange thing that I noticed is if I get rid of "jquery.easing.1.3.min.js" which is being called on every page, it randomly fixes itself.  I can confirm that it was working fine with that same script being called in for the past month or so.

It might be something in my custom.js which is causing the problem, but if i completely delete it, the issue isn't fixed which leads me to believe that it's not the issue.

Here is the file that I have the code for fancybox specifically in: http://www.remodeling-buffalo.com/resource/js/filter-masonry.js

code being:

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*  Fancybox
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

(function() {

    // Images
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  : 'fade',
        'transitionOut' : 'fade',
        'titlePosition' : 'over'
    }).each(function() {
        $(this).append('<span class="zoom">&nbsp;</span>');
    });

    // Iframe
    $('.iframe').fancybox({
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'fade',
        'transitionOut' : 'fade',
        'type'          : 'iframe',
        'titleShow'     : false
    }).each(function() {
        $(this).append('<span class="zoom">&nbsp;</span>');
    });

})();

/* end Fancybox */
```

I just have no idea what's wrong though as everything seems to be the same as it used to be, but why does removing "jquery.easing.1.3.min.js" randomly fix the issue?

Not sure what else I can post here that could be useful, but here is the location of custom.js: http://www.remodeling-buffalo.com/resource/js/custom.js

No idea what could be causing the problem or what I can post on here to help.  No error messages are popping up in javascript or anything from console, so I really can't even begin to figure out what's wrong.

Thanks so much guys, I really appreciate it as I'v been stressing about this for weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you're using jQuery 1.8.0. Fancybox 2 doesn't work well with jQuery 1.8.0. Downgrading to jQuery 1.7.2 should fix your problem.

See https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/339 for this specific issue. It seems there's a PNG fix, since fancybox_overlay.png was added 7 days ago: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/tree/master/source

Comment: O..M...F..G.. Thank you SO MUCH for pointing this out!  I was so confused as I didn't remember changing anything and the problem came out of nowhere, but it was the update which did it.. I don't know how to thank you! I spent SO MUCH TIME trying to figure out what the problem was, thank you SOSOSOSOSOSO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The [FancyBox site](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) shows you how to do this. See "Change overlay color and opacity" under "Tips & tricks". In short, you add a "helpers" element to the object you pass to fancybox.

In your case it should look something like this:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    transitionIn  : 'fade',
    transitionOut : 'fade',
    titlePosition : 'over',
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            opacity: 0.2,
            css : { 'background-color' : '#000' }
        }
    }
}).each(function() {
    $(this).append('<span class="zoom">&nbsp;</span>');
});
```

Comment: No, I mean I'v tried this and it doesn't fix it.  There is some kind of issue that is happening against other scripts I have running I mean.  This doesn't fix it, it's some other script that is giving it this issue which I can't figure out.  I appreciate the suggestion though /:

Comment: OK, fair enough. I checked your page against the Fancybox example and the opacity for the overlay is set to a different value. On your site, `fancybox-overlay` has `opacity:0` while the FB site has `opacity:0.8`. It's an inline style so I have no idea why it wouldn't be set to the correct value.

Comment: Hmm.. all of my fancybox CSS is set to 0.8, I checked inside of of the JS too, and changed all of the values from 0 to 0.8, and it didn't change anything.  I mean what's weird is that when I take out easing.js then it fixes itself.. Like something inside that script is interfering with something?

Comment: Yes, it could be a problem with the easing functions calculating opacity. What exactly are you using it for? It's just a collection of functions but I don't see you using those functions anywhere.

Comment: I use the easing function so it can scroll down the page.  Visit any of the interior pages, I use it for smooth-scroll and on the homepage for the slider.  I'm confused because I'v had it on the site since the beginning and it's always worked fine with being called on all pages.  Fancybox never had a problem until a recent update I did.  I went back on all of my files though (as I backup the site daily) and just couldn't figure out where the problem was, I feel like I tried absolutely everything /: